# WPF make columns overflow grid

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

WPF make columns overflow grid. The problem is, that I have to much columns to show them properly. When I read in data, the columns overflow the grid, but if I resize the form on high resolution screen and stretch one column, it wont push others out of the grid and will have maximum possible width, which is not enough. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Post the relevant XAML and a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I cant. If I could, I would post.

Comment: You'll need to explain the problem more completely then, preferably using WPF terminology. What are the column widths set to? What's the behavior you're actually trying to get? How is that different from what you're getting?

Comment: You can't post XAML?  Why not?

Comment: Column widths all are static positive integers except for last column, which had width="*", and that was the problem. Dont really understand why, but I could guess, that its just how it is implemented. Problem started when I tried to stretch column and it stoped to stretch at one point (width was to small to read data), then I noticed, that problem was in columns - they tried to keep in view (didnt overflow over the grid and turned on vertical scroll bar), I was expecting that the columns would go out of view and create vertical scroll bar in datagrid visible part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have star sizing on the column definitions? If you do then it would try to fit all columns with in the given parent width.
Put Auto or absolute values for column widths and make sure that ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility is set to Visible or Auto.

Let me know if it helps, otherwise you should post your XAML code here.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Well this was the solution. I had this in xaml <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"></DataGridTemplateColumn>. I couldnt post all xaml, because it contained business data I cant show to everyone.